# How to attach multiple objects to an armature?

Tags: animation

[image]

How do I move the yellow earrings along with the goblin head movement?
I tried joining them all but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first delete all vertex group, second, click in earrings, click in armature, go to pose mode select just bone head and press ctrl + p, select bone